# Release of my c# application doesn't work on other machines "Microsoft office Interop Excel"

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I tried to release my project on c# and got its setup file. I used it on my own laptop and everything works. But after installing the app on other machines, I get the following Error:
`the COM-Object from Type: System___ComObject cannot be converted to the interface "Micorsoft Office Interop Excel" Application`.

Do you guys have any idea, what does that mean?

Comment: Is MS Excel actually installed on these other computers?

Comment: Make sure the dll for the Excel library is carried over with the install on other machines.

Comment: how can i carry over the dll Excel Library with the install ?

Comment: Same way you move your .exe file over. You should find it in your project's bin folder. `\{ProjectName}\bin\Release`. Look for the dll in that folder. If it's not, check the `\{ProjectName}\bin\Debug` folder and copy it over. ** Note: folder format is generated by Visual Studio, not sure how it would look in other compilers.

Comment: i dont find any .dll documents there

Comment: What do you mean by _installing the app on other machines_? What is it that you installed there? Is it just the _TheAppName.exe_ file or is there an installer involved?

Comment: I did a full installer for the app. I didn't only copy the .exe file

Comment: What is included in the installer (.exe files, DLLs,...)? Which installer are you using (Inno Setup, Install Shield, ...)? What are the contents of the installation directory after the installer did its job? What is the target platform your application is build against (x86, x64, Any CPU)?

Comment: If it isn't the dll, this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dau-blog/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-_application/) might help you. Long shot in the dark though...

Comment: @Aladin set `Copy Local` true at the reference properties. Then rebuild the project. The .dll should be now in your Debug folder.

Comment: When you set up your deployment, did you specify any frameworks or other prerequisites?

Comment: If you've referenced Excel Interop, the .dlls will be in the output folder. But that doesn't do any good at all if the correct version of Excel isn't installed on the other computer. That is one of the many, many reasons why Interop will make you sad. Even if you've invested a decent amount of time in it, I'd still consider rewriting using EPPlus. Interop just has too many creative ways to mess with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to convert or type cast a **Com Object** to **Microsoft.Interop.Excel.Application** which is actually not an Excel.Application Object.